# Does the question will be bumped to top of queue when it get edited?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

As I know that we are not suggested to post a repeating question although the first question we get are less attention. Does editing my original question in Stack Overflow will bump it to the top of the active queue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing your question will 'bump' it to the top of several lists, but don't do this solely to get more attention to your question. If you think your question isn't getting enough attention, you should [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it.

Abusing edits to bump your question isn't allowed. Edits should only be used to add or fix information.